# How to force Chrome/Firefox/Opera to do crossdomain requests from localhost?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, cross-domain

Hy,

So I've got this problem: I'm trying to develop an HTML file on my localhost, and all the browsers I have installed are preventing me to send cross-domain requests.

What I'm trying to do is to convert a script I wrote in Python (with Mechanize, pyquery and lxml) to Javascript, the reasons don't really matter (I thought in Javascript it would be easier to simulate something).

Cross-domain requests from local files used to work, and are still working on the latest Safari (stable), but I can't install Safari on this machine (it's a Linux box).

**EDIT**

I discovered the escalated privileges of Firefox, e.g.:

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
// among others
```

Problem is, I'm also trying to access the content loaded in an iFrame ... as I said, I'm trying to simulate a browser session, like I would with a library like Mechanize, but from Javascript. My script still works in Safari.

**So how to force Chrome / Firefox / Opera to bypass all security restrictions from locally stored files?**

I'm interested in a browser command-line option, I would even consider a patch to the browser (I'm the user, not trying to distribute this to anyone else).

Thanks,

Comment: Not really an answer, but this under the hood article from Google talks about how they used JSONP because of browser limitations with same-origin requests: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/11/instant-previews-under-hood.html

Comment: Yeah, but it's too limiting for me. I got some code that loads a website in an iFrame, and I'm trying to manipulate its content from Javascript: i.e. just an automation of a task I previously did with Python's mechanize.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure whether or not you have control of the content in the IFrames but since you are speaking of local files I guess you do. [This article](http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-domain-iframe-communication-without-location-polling) on  Ajaxian should cover your use case.
Since you are targeting grade A browsers (e.i. not IE) you could use html5 window.postMessage instead of IFrames.

Cheers, Jon.

I have no working knowledge of Python Mechanize lib.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start a simple http server instead to solve your problem?

```
import sys
import BaseHTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler


HandlerClass = SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
ServerClass  = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
Protocol     = "HTTP/1.0"

if sys.argv[1:]:
    port = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
    port = 8000
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', port)

HandlerClass.protocol_version = Protocol
httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass)

sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()
print "Serving HTTP on", sa[0], "port", sa[1], "..."
httpd.serve_forever()
```

This python code will start a simple http server listening on port 8000 or the first argument and handles all files in the folder from this script.

Comment: Doesn't help with this issue though.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood question a little bit. I try and have second look at this later, when I have some time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works when the page is on localhost, but it might be worth a try: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

That jQuery plugin lets you make cross-domain requests from any domain... Perhaps it might work with localhost? Haven't tested it though.